# sbt: cobertura4sbt cannot be found from sbt 0.12

Tags: plugins, sbt, cobertura

I am about to use [cobertura4sbt](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/de/johoop/cobertura4sbt/1.0.0/) sbt plugin from maven repository.

I added the following lines to `project\plugins.sbt`:

```scala
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools"

addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "cobertura4sbt" % "1.0.0")
```

However, as I tried to "sbt compile", it always appended my local SBT and Scala version number to the resolving path so that the corresponding pom cannot be found. Do I miss something anywhere?

```
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn] https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/de/johoop/cobertura4sbt_2.9.2_0.12/1.0.0/cobertura4sbt-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
```

Answer (score 1):

### cobertura4sbt on sbt 0.7.4

The auto-postfixing of Scala and sbt version was added a while back in sbt to distinguish plugins for different releases of sbt. From [this source](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/cobertura4sbt/src/4954ec83901fb2d40eab086c9d3d93cf28e454a2/project/build.properties?at=default), cobertura4sbt looks like it was built for 0.7.4, but the author [says](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/cobertura4sbt/wiki/Home) the plugin is no longer maintained:

> This SBT plug-in enables you to measure your code coverage with the help of the great Cobertura tool.
>
> However, since Cobertura is not really actively developed any more, I decided to stop working on this plugin for the time being, and instead started jacoco4sbt. Please ponder using [jacoco4sbt](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/jacoco4sbt) instead of this plugin...

jacoco4sbt seems to be available for the latest sbt 0.13.0 too. Either plugin you choose, follow the instruction in the wiki.

### jacoco4sbt on sbt 0.12.x

Given the log, I am assuming you're using sbt 0.12.x. jacoco4sbt for sbt 0.12 is published at Sonatype OSS, and the latest seems to be 2.0.0: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/de/johoop/jacoco4sbt_2.9.2_0.12/2.0.0/

Try putting this in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.0.0")
```

and in `jacoco.sbt`:

```scala
jacoco.settings
```

This loads `jacoco:cover` task into sbt shell, which I was able to run and get the report out in `target/scala-2.10/jacoco` directory.

Comment: Thanks. This is nothing with which plugin is used. I tried jacoco4sbt, the same issue is applied. That said, local sbt and scala version are always appeneded to the search path which results in search failure.